# How to HTTP PUT a file in Powershell and capture response body?

Tags: powershell, curl, upload

I'd like to upload a file using powershell and capture the resulting response body. How can one do this?

I've tried:

> $env:DEPLOY_URL = & curl.exe https://make.mudlet.org/snapshots/Mudlet-$env:VERSION$env:MUDLET_VERSION_BUILD-windows.zip --upload-file Mudlet-$env:VERSION$env:MUDLET_VERSION_BUILD-windows.zip 2>&1

But that does not work and says `Command executed with exception:` without listing the exception.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Explore using the [`Invoke-RestMethod`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.utility/invoke-restmethod?view=powershell-6) command. You can save the response body using the `-OutFile` parameter.

An example `PUT` would be as follows where `$uri` is the destination, `$inFile` is the path to the local file, and `$outFile` is the path to where to save the response body:

`Invoke-RestMethod -Uri $uri -Method PUT -InFile $inFile -OutFile $outFile`